# prove a set that the coordination multiplication is bigger than a certain value to be convex set

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a set here 
$$\{(x,y)|xy \geq c, x>0, y>0\}$$
how to prove this set is a convex set for any c?

Namely, how to prove 
$$(\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha)x_2)(\alpha y_1+(1-\alpha)y_2)\geq c, \forall 1>\alpha>0$$ if $x_1y_1\geq c$ and $x_2y_2\geq c$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $c>0$ (otherwise it's obvious). Now
\begin{align} (\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha)x_2)(\alpha y_1+(1-\alpha)y_2) &= \alpha^2x_1y_1 + \alpha(1-\alpha)x_2y_1 + \alpha(1-\alpha)x_1y_2 + (1-\alpha)^2x_2y_2 \\
&\ge(\alpha^2+(1-\alpha)^2)c + \alpha(1-\alpha)(x_2y_1+x_1y_2).
\end{align}
By AM-GM, we have
$$x_2y_1+x_1y_2\ge 2\sqrt{x_2y_1x_1y_2} \ge 2c $$
and hence
$$ (\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha)x_2)(\alpha y_1+(1-\alpha)y_2) \ge c(\alpha^2+(1-\alpha)^2+2\alpha(1-\alpha)) = c(\alpha+(1-\alpha))^2 = c$$
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the definition.  Take two points $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ with $xy \ge c, x'y'\ge c$.  Parameterize the line segment connecting them and show that for all points $(a,b)$ on the segment, $ab \ge c$.  You really don't care about the value of $c$ because the proof goes through if you divide $c$ and all the $x$ values (alternately all the $y$ values) by $c$.  The argument changes a bit if $c \le 0$

Comment: The actual problem is exactly I can't prove:
$$(ax+(1-a)x')(ay+(1-a)y')\geq c$$